# COUNT with active record?

Tags: php, codeigniter, count

I use in a database. but I want to use in CodeIgniter. How can I do this with CodeIgniter using the active record query method? Can this be done with COUNT po_id?

```
SELECT position.po_name AS position, activity.ac_name AS activity ,
COUNT(register.po_id) AS regis FROM register
INNER JOIN activity ON register.ac_id = activity.ac_id
INNER JOIN position ON register.po_id = position.po_id
WHERE register.regis_status = 2 AND activity.ac_id = 2
GROUP BY register.ac_id,register.po_id


regis_status | ac_id | po_id
-----------------------------
     2       |   4   |  2
     2       |   2   |  2
     2       |   2   |  2
     3       |   2   |  2
     3       |   2   |  2
     1       |   3   |  2
     2       |   3   |  1
     1       |   7   |  2
```

Answer (score 0):

If the query is correct .Try this

```
$this->db->select('position.po_name AS position, activity.ac_name AS activity , COUNT(register.po_id) AS regis')
     ->from('register')
     ->join('activity', 'register.ac_id = activity.ac_id','INNER')
     ->join('position ', 'register.po_id = position.po_id','INNER')
     ->where('register.regis_status', 2)
     ->where('activity.ac_id', $ac_id)
     //more where ->where() 
     ->group_by('register.ac_id,register.po_id');
```

Comment: if I have 2 where such as WHERE register.regis_status = 2 AND activity.ac_id => $ac_id. How I write?

Comment: Is it woking? @Book